# Extract part of a URL with URL/URI objects

Tags: java

I have a String holding a URL in this format: http://hello.world.com/service/sps/f4c0e810456t
And I would like to extract the last part of the URL, i.e. f4c0e810456t.

I can do it with substrings:

```
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, s.length()));
```

Or regexp however looking for something more elegant using URL/URI objects but couldn't find something.

Any ideas...?

Comment: This is what the Java tutorial says about parsing URLs, your requirement does not seem to be part of the list - at least it will deal with weir URLs (queries etc.): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with URL and split (it wrap regular expression for you):

```
    String address = "http://hello.world.com/service/sps/f4c0e810456t";
    URL url = new URL(address);

     String [] str = url.getPath().split("/");
     String result = str[str.length-1];
```

Comment: I expected something more "built in" to these Objects that I might be missing but that will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the URL to "http://hello.world.com/service/sps/?f4c0e810456t" then you could use the `getQuery()` method (both on URL and URI).